# ASSERT: "false" in file qasciikey.cpp, line 495

Tags: opencv, assert

I am using openCV to display some image in a loop. I use imshow() to display image and then uses cv::waitKey(10) for allowing to draw window.

I get error ASSERT: "false" in file qasciikey.cpp, line 495, whenever I press keys to dim screen light. Basically If I keep pressed light key(F2 or F1) while waitKey(10) is running it throws error.
I have tried all other combinations but I get error on some keys. I want my code error proof, so that if someone accidentally press key my code should not abort. I also tried to catch error and ignore it using try_catch but it doesn't catch ASSERT error.

Note: I only get error if I select image window as active window and then press some keys. Though I can run code without pressing keys, but it is a machine learning setup and it requires 10-12 hours to train. I don't want sudden abortion of code due to some key press.

Please help.

Comment: File a bug on the OpenCV github. | If the software is training a network for half a day, why do you need `imshow` and `waitKey` in there?

Comment: Actually I am using imshow to display graph Image for learning curve to track its progress. Though I can use other approaches but just wanted to know what is exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

put the cv2.waitKey before the cv2.imshows works for me.